# anchor click doesn't open the modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's how I have an anchor tag with me.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTC">terms and conditions</a>
```

My modal looks like below

```
<!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="modalTC" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehmepvya/).

I am not sure what's going wrong. 
PS: I do have the related files with me. ie. Bootstrap and Jquery.

Comment: Check 1: `jquery.(min.)js` & `bootstrap.(min.)js` both loaded, in this order. Check 2: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle? Check 3: If you can't the trouble is with some other script in your page which bound on click and either cancels the event or returns false before it gets to bootstrap.js event.

Comment: Have you checked console ?

Comment: I found your problem your forgot to reference Jquery Js in your page. Checkout your console

Comment: Ah my bad. Thanks guys.

@charlietfl Ah but in case If it is here, People shouldn't try being the Nazis.

Comment: So you are saying that because you are too lazy to look for errors that we should accept bad questions? Everyone that answered looked at error in console. What does german politics have to do with anything here also?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're calling `bootstrap.min.js` after `jquery.min.js`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css>

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTC">terms and conditions</a>


<!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="modalTC" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working fine. Try this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTC">terms and conditions</a>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfcqhyus/)

I think you forgot to add JS and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You load Bootstrap before jQuery.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTC">terms and conditions</a>


<!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="modalTC" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call jQuery first (before bootstrap.min.js) :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehmepvya/1/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and add three files bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js, bootstrap.min.js locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Modal Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTC">terms and conditions</a>
     <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="modalTC" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: And add three files as I mentioned above.

Comment: code is fine. Only the problem is may be you forget to add js and css file.So use js and css file saved locally.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jquery file before bootstrap.js. here is you fiddle updated: `jsfiddle.net/dssoft32/ehmepvya/2/`

Bootstrap framework is depended upon jquery. So you have to include jquery first. order of importing files play a great role in java script.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Launch demo modal </a>
```

OR refer this ..  https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

another one things to keep in mind that you need to load jquery for that so make sure that you loaded it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you've included bootstrap and jquery? I've just added

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and it works fine